# how can i move to a specific slide in FlowSlider jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using **FlowSlider jquery plugin** for show some images horizontally. you can see some Examples and API Documention in [FlowSlider Website](http://www.flowslider.com)

but my Question is that what is a way for go to a specific slide(for example #6) by Click on a button for example .i can not find any solution for that.
if you know please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin does not seem to deal with items.

It treats the whole slider area as a single animated element.

The only thing you can do is set the position of the slider with

```
var API = $('#slideid')[0].FlowSlider;
API.position(0.4); // where 0.4 means 40% of the total allowed movement of the slider..
```